# Android textview wont update outside oncreate

Tags: java, android

I have an text view (Text1) that updates fine when i set the text in the `oncreate` but when i try to update it in the onEvent method it doesn't update I have searched similar posts but cant narrow down whats causing my specific problem

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ProximityManager.ProximityListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProximityManagerContract proximityManager;
    private ScanContext scanContext;
    private TextView Text1;
    private TextView Text2;
    private TextView Text3;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        KontaktSDK.initialize("").setDebugLoggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setLogLevelEnabled(LogLevel.DEBUG, true);
        ;
        proximityManager = new KontaktProximityManager(this);

        Text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        proximityManager.initializeScan(getScanContext(), new OnServiceReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                proximityManager.attachListener(MainActivity.this);


                EddystoneScanContext eddystoneScanContext = new EddystoneScanContext.Builder()
                        .setEventTypes(Arrays.asList(
                                EventType.SPACE_ENTERED,
                                EventType.DEVICES_UPDATE,
                                EventType.SPACE_ABANDONED))
                        .build();


                ScanContext scanContext = new ScanContext.Builder()
                        .setEddystoneScanContext(eddystoneScanContext)
                        .build();



            }


            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailure() {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        proximityManager.detachListener(this);
        proximityManager.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(BluetoothDeviceEvent bluetoothDeviceEvent) {
        final List<? extends RemoteBluetoothDevice> deviceList = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getDeviceList();
        long timestamp = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getTimestamp();
        DeviceProfile deviceProfile = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getDeviceProfile();


        switch (bluetoothDeviceEvent.getEventType()) {
            case SPACE_ENTERED:
                Log.d(TAG, "namespace or region entered");
                break;
            case DEVICE_DISCOVERED:
                Log.d(TAG, "found new beacon");
                break;
            case DEVICES_UPDATE:

                Log.d(TAG, "updated beacons");
                Log.d("Scan", String.valueOf(deviceProfile.toString()));
                Log.d("List", deviceList.toString());
                //Log.d("List", deviceProfile.name(deviceList.get(1)));
                Log.d("distance", String.valueOf(deviceList.get(1).getDistance()));


                Text1.setText("Is Updated");

                break;
            case DEVICE_LOST:
                Log.d(TAG, "lost device");
                break;
            case SPACE_ABANDONED:
                Log.d(TAG, "namespace or region abandoned");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "scan started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "scan stopped");
    }


    private ScanContext getScanContext() {
        if (scanContext == null) {
            scanContext = new ScanContext.Builder()
                    .setScanPeriod(ScanPeriod.RANGING) // or for monitoring for 15 seconds scan and 10 seconds waiting:
                            //.setScanPeriod(new ScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)))
                    .setScanMode(ProximityManager.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .setActivityCheckConfiguration(ActivityCheckConfiguration.MINIMAL)
                    .setForceScanConfiguration(ForceScanConfiguration.MINIMAL)
                    .setIBeaconScanContext(new IBeaconScanContext.Builder().build())
                    .setEddystoneScanContext(new EddystoneScanContext.Builder().build())
                    .setForceScanConfiguration(ForceScanConfiguration.MINIMAL)
                    .build();
        }
        return scanContext;
    }

}
```

Comment: is it even entering the case where you are updating textview? Does the  Log statement gets printed in Logcat?

Comment: yes the Logcat prints but the textview doesn't update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update view outside the main thread (UI thread). Try to wrap your method with runOnUiThread.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Text1.setText("Is Updated");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Text1.setText("Is Updated");
        }
    });
```

you have to use `Handler` or `runOnUIThread` because you cant edit on a component in main thread from outside

Comment: I think that statement is already on UI thread, If it was on background thread the app would have crashed